# Como deixar o resultado de um while em lista?

Tags: python, array, lista, for, while

Como deixar o resultado desse código em Python em forma de lista (40, 39, 38, 37, 36)?

```python
temperatura = 40
while temperatura > 35:
    print(temperatura)
    temperatura = temperatura - 1
```

Comment: `>>> temps = list(range(40,35,-1))` e `>>> print(temps)` veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/3rzc5Z

Comment: Se for só pra imprimir e nada mais (ou seja, se não precisa guardar os valores): `print(tuple(range(40, 35, -1)))`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Primeiro crie uma nova variável do tipo list(), depois adicione os valores de temperatura a essa lista com o método append(), e para retirar o ultimo valor da lista utilize o método pop().

```python
temperatura = 40
list_temperatura = list()
while temperatura >= 36:
    list_temperatura.append(temperatura)
    temperatura = temperatura - 1
print(list_temperatura)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).